# bad argument 1 to sizeof() error in pike

Tags: sizeof, pike

I wrote a big program in pike, and suddenly it gives me an error it didn't give me before:

> bad argument 1 to sizeof().

Does someone know the problem? what can I do? it worked before. That's the code:

```
int main()
{
  string path;
  path=Stdio.Readline()->read("enter a path");   
  add_module_path(path);
  array fileArr=get_dir(path);
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  while (j != sizeof(fileArr))
  {
    // ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: `add_module_path(path);` seems unrelated to the example given here. i'd remove it from the example code.

Answer (score 1):

if the given path does not exist, then `get_dir()` will return `0`.

`0` is an invalid argument to `sizeof()`.

check the relevant values before passing them on.

the simplest in this case:

```
while (arrayp(fileArr) && j != sizeof(fileArr))
```

you could also `stat()` the path before passing it to `get_dir()`